# Data.table: creating new variables, subsetting by date periods, grouping by second variable, x, and aggregating results by final date of each x

Tags: r, data.table

I am completely new to data.table, so please bear with me. In the following example, I would like to create two new columns in my dataset: the total purchase price within two different time periods for each customer ID. So far, I have that working.

However, I get stuck when trying to subset the data. I would like to subset the data so that each row represents a unique customer ID along with their final purchase price, final purchase date, period 1 purchase price total, and their period 2 purchase price total.

I thought that data.table might replicate the computed totals over all rows corresponding to each customer. However, it only replicates those totals in rows corresponding to the period intervals specified in the table's *i* index. Since it does not replicate those totals over all rows for each customer, my final dplyr block does not do the trick.

In the second and third code blocks I will give the output of the final dplyr code and then what the output I would like to achieve.

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(custid = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4)),
                   purchase.price = seq(1, 32, by=2),
                   date = seq.Date(from=as.Date("2015-01-01"), to=as.Date("2015-01-16"), by="days"))

period_intervals <- list(period_one = interval(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-01-09")),
                         period_two = interval(as.Date("2015-01-10"), as.Date("2015-01-16")))

data <- as.data.table(data)
data <- data[order(date)]
setkey(data, custid)

data <- data[date %within% period_intervals[[1]], 
             period.1.price.total := sum(purchase.price), 
             by = custid]

data <- data[date %within% period_intervals[[2]], 
             period.2.price.total := sum(purchase.price), 
             by = custid]

data_sub <- data %>%
  group_by(custid) %>%
  arrange(desc(date)) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)
```

Current result:

```
  custid purchase.price      date       period.1.price.total period.2.price.total
   <dbl>     <dbl>          <date>              <dbl>              <dbl>
     1         31         2015-01-16              NA                112
     2         23         2015-01-12              NA                 63
```

Finally, what I am aiming for:

```
 custid purchase.price      date       period.1.price.total period.2.price.total
   <dbl>     <dbl>          <date>              <dbl>              <dbl>
     1         31         2015-01-16              33                112
     2         23         2015-01-12              48                 63
```

Comment: how did you create the 'total' column?

Comment: Fyi, Akrun might generously work with you as you change your question, but it's usually considered bad etiquette here to change a question after an answer has resolved the question as initially posted. I've done it myself, telling the answerer "let me know if you'd rather I revert the edit and post a separate question" rather than suggesting they should be expected to "bear with" me. It's a pretty minor thing in my mind, but you can get a backlash for it.

Comment: @akrun the 'total' column in the result blocks was a typo, I went ahead and edited it.

Comment: @Frank thank you for the heads up, I didn't mean to be rude by editing the question, but I can see how that is bad form. For the future, would it be better to add a new question and reference the original question it is an extension to?

Comment: It depends on how much of an extension it is and what the answerer thinks about it, I guess. Usually, I'll just make the edit and then ask the answerer's opinion.

Comment: The edited version looks completely different problem.

Comment: @akrun thank you for your help, I am editing this post and posting a new question for the case where I am creating many more variables dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by subsetting the purchase.price with the index

```
data[, .(period.1.total.sum = sum(purchase.price[date %within% 
                     period_intervals[[1]]])),by = custid]
```

For creating the columns simultaneously, we can use `Map`

```
nm1 <- c('period.1. total.sum', 'period.2.total.sum')
data[,  (nm1) := Map(function(x,y) sum(purchase.price[x %within% y]), 
                   list(date), period_intervals), by = custid] 
data[order(custid, -date)][,.SD[1:.N==1] , custid]
#   custid purchase.price       date period.1. total.sum period.2.total.sum
#1:      1             23 2015-01-12                  33                 63
#2:      2             31 2015-01-16                  48                112
```

NOTE: The 'total' column creation code was not showed in the OP's post.

Comment: What if I was computing the total, the mean, and the median of the purchase price over 12 time periods for each customer and finally wanted to  keep all that information in the row corresponding to the final purchase date for each customer?

Comment: @ToddYoung In that case, create those columns also in the 'data' and subset later i.e. `data[, c('Total', 'Mean', 'Median') := .(.N, mean(purchase.price), median(purchase.price)), by = custid]`

Comment: Sorry to make things more complicated, but let me edit my post to add at the end what I am looking at in my data. I tried to simplify the problem thinking that I would not be able to explain my problem well enough. Again, bear with me, I am pretty new at this.