# Data.table: dynamically creating variables over various subsets of data and grouping by variable x, subsetting final results

Tags: r, data.table

I am creating three types of variables over multiple time periods for individual customer IDs in my data. These new variables include the sum of a price vector, the mean of a price vector, and the mean difference between successive dates in a date vector.

Using data.table, I am looping through multiple time periods, subsetting the data in each period, and calculating those variables for individual customer IDs. Each of these variables are named dynamically as I loop over the time periods. As it stands, these variables are being computed correctly.

Here is where I am getting stuck: after all of these variables are computed, I would like to subset the data to include the new aggregated variables along with the most recent purchase.price and date elements for each customer.

I thought that data.table might replicate the computed totals over all rows corresponding to each customer. However, it only replicates those totals in rows corresponding to the period intervals specified in the table's i index. Since it does not replicate those totals over all rows for each customer, my final dplyr block does not do the trick.

In the second and third code blocks I will give the output of the final dplyr code and then what the output I would like to achieve.

This question stems from a similar problem noted where we are [subsetting over fewer variables that are not being created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989688/data-table-creating-new-variables-subsetting-by-date-periods-grouping-by-seco).

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(custid = c(rep(1, 25), rep(2, 25), rep(1, 25), rep(2, 25)),
                   purchase.price = seq(1, 200, by=2),
                   date = seq.Date(from=as.Date("2015-01-01"), to=as.Date("2015-04-10"), by="days"))

period_intervals <- list(period_one = interval(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-01-30")),
                         period_two = interval(as.Date("2015-02-01"), as.Date("2015-02-28")),
                         period_three = interval(as.Date("2015-03-01"), as.Date("2015-03-31")),
                         period_four = interval(as.Date("2015-04-01"), as.Date("2015-04-28")))


data <- as.data.table(data)
data <- data[order(date)]
setkey(data, custid)

time_periods <- c(1:4)

for(i in time_periods[1]:max(time_periods)){
    data <- data[date %within% period_intervals[[i]], 
                 paste("period", i, "price.sum", sep="."):= sum(purchase.price), 
                 by = custid]

    data <- data[date %within% period_intervals[[i]], 
                 paste("period", i, "price.mean", sep="."):= mean(purchase.price), 
                 by = custid]

    data <- data[date %within% period_intervals[[i]],
                 paste("period", i, "mean.diff.date", sep="."):= mean(as.numeric(diff(purchase.price))),
                 by = custid]
}

data_sub <- data %>%
  group_by(custid) %>%
  arrange(desc(date)) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)
```

Current result from dplyr subsetting (showing the first 7 columns):

```
  custid purchase.price       date period.1.price.sum period.1.price.mean period.1.mean.diff.date period.2.price.sum ...
   <dbl>          <dbl>     <date>              <dbl>              <dbl>                   <dbl>              <dbl> ...
1      2            199 2015-04-10                 NA                 NA                      NA                 NA ...
2      1            149 2015-03-16                 NA                 NA                      NA                 NA ...
```

Here is what I was hoping for (showing first 7 columns):

```
      custid purchase.price       date period.1.price.sum period.1.price.mean period.1.mean.diff.date period.2.price.sum ...
       <dbl>          <dbl>     <date>              <dbl>              <dbl>                   <dbl>              <dbl> ...
    1      2            199 2015-04-10                625                 25                       2                981 ...
    2      1            149 2015-03-16                275                 55                       2                1539 ...
```

Note:

In my complete dataset, I am looping over anywhere between 10-20 time periods. The number of periods to be computed over is subject to change, thus my approach to dynamically create the new variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` as in the previous post

```
nm1 <- sprintf("%s.%d.%s", "period", seq_along(period_intervals), "price.sum")
nm2 <- sprintf("%s.%d.%s", "period", seq_along(period_intervals), "price.mean")
nm3 <- sprintf("%s.%d.%s", "period", seq_along(period_intervals), "mean.diff.date")
data[,   c(rbind(nm1, nm2, nm3)) := unlist(Map(function(x,y) {
         x1 <- purchase.price[x %within% y]
         list(sum(x1), mean(x1), mean(as.numeric(diff(x1))))},
                   list(date), period_intervals), recursive = FALSE), by = custid]
data[order(custid, -date)][,.SD[1] , custid]
```

Comment: that looks great! I am wondering why the mean date difference for customer 1 in period 3 is NaN. Looking at `cust1_period3 <- data %>%
  filter(custid == 1 & date %within% period_intervals[[3]]) %>%
  mutate(period.3.mean.diff.date = mean(as.numeric(diff(date))))` returns a mean date difference of 1?

Comment: @ToddYoung I think the column names got interchanged

Comment: @ToddYoung Your code in the post is `diff(purchase.price)` and here in the comments it is `diff(date)`.  I was following your post.  Otherwise, it looks fine for me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you mean. This might be the fault of me calling the original data set 'data', if we make a copy of the original data example and call it 'data.check', and then run `cust1_period3 <- data.check %>% filter(custid == 1 & date %within% period_intervals[[3]]) %>% mutate(period.3.mean.diff.date = mean(as.numeric(diff(date))))` , the result gives a mean difference of dates for customer 1 = 1. Does that fix it?

Comment: @ToddYoung Please check your code in your post.  It is `mean(as.numeric(diff(purchase.price)))`

Comment: shoot, you're right. That is a typo. With that, everything works as expected.